# How can I mint a token without a name for NFT royalties?

Tags: nft, native-assets, minting

The proposal for Cardano NFT royalties [CIP-0027](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/pull/116/files) suggests that a *nameless token* should be used to store the royalties information.

Usually a mint transaction looks something like this:

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
--mary-era \
--fee 195509 \
--tx-in b1ddb0347fed2aecc7f00caabaaf2634f8e2d17541f6237bbed78e2092e1c414#0 \
--tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+4804491+"1 677d3bbe3e01eeab498cd8786f7d261d92bd6ecea12109a332e86374.MountainGorilla"\
--mint="1 677d3bbe3e01eeab498cd8786f7d261d92bd6ecea12109a332e86374.MountainGorilla"\
--out-file matx.raw
```

> Source: https://silas-stulz.medium.com/you-want-to-create-your-own-nft-heres-how-you-do-it-on-the-cardano-blockchain-9a0bbf8caa39

As we can see in the `mint` part, the new token is a combination of the policy id `677d...` and the token name `MountainGorilla`.

Is there any example how a nameless token can be minted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native assets as far as I’m aware can have the empty string for the token name. In theory you should be able to just leave the token name empty so the token ID will just be the policy ID. I’m not sure if the `.` is still required though, but as you can see from the docs, it’s just a ByteString object, which can be empty.

https://alpha.marlowe.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V1-Ledger-Value.html#g:2